# Most efficient way to check strings between two HTML <select>?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kinda a newbie with Javascript and was proposed a problem of this sort. I have to fetch all files in a directory in PHP, then I have to list these files in two HTML `<select>` lists. The first one contains the extensions of the files I find in the directory while the second one contains the full filenames. When i select an extension (with an onchange in the first select) ALL the files that don't have that extension must be removed from the second `<select>`. The thing should work like this: I select "jpg" and all the files that aren't .jpg files must be removed from the second select. I made a function to manage this but it doesn't work as it should. Here I am posting the code I made:

```
echo("function visible_selection(){
    var ext = document.getElementById(\"ext\");
    var slen = document.getElementById(\"files\").length;
    var selected = ext.options[ext.selectedIndex].text;
    var filez = document.getElementById(\"files\");
    for(var i=0; i < slen; i++){
        var vdump = filez.options[i].text;
        var xcase = vdump.split(\".\");
        if (!vdump.includes(selected) && xcase[1] != selected){
            filez.remove(i);
        }
    }
    filez.style.display = \"inline\";
}");
```

ext is obviously the first `<select>` that contains the extensions, while files is the second one with the full filenames. My question is, how can I correctly check if the extension is contained in the filename and therefore delete the files that don't have that kind of extension?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem than "it doesn't work".  Consider this an opportunity to practice some debugging.  How specifically does it fail?  In your browser's debugging console, are there any errors?  When you use your browser's script debugger to step through the code as it executes, what specifically happens?  Which operation produces an unexpected result?

Comment: The Chrome console says `Cannot read property 'text' of undefined at visible_selection(line 7) which would be the **var vdump** assignment

Comment: Still, the function has an incorrect way to check these strings, as way more files than expected remain in the second `<select>` after the function's execution.

Comment: Time to debug from that error then.  The object that is `undefined`, where should it have come from?  As you define each variable, either pause in the debugger to observe its value or use `console.log()` to output that variable to the console.  Which value isn't what you expect it to be?  For example, if something should be an element based on that element's `id` but is `undefined`, then that element `id` isn't found.  So look at the HTML, what is the element you were trying to find?

Comment: Ok so the error appears to be related to the filenames select, which has the _files_ id. In the console using `console.log()` it shows the select without issues though, so perhaps the error is in the for cycle?

Comment: This is a very common mistake. I would recommend putting a `console.log(vdump)` inside the loop. just after you define vdump

Comment: If the select is correct, then which value is incorrect?  If I were to guess, `slen` might not be what you assume it is.  Check every variable.  The point of debugging isn't to guess things like "perhaps the error is in the for cycle", it's to validate the result of each operation and find the very first operation which produces an unexpected result.  It's a systematic process.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend working with something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/spliffmon/dgrt7e1q/29/) to remove the php side of things and removing the reliance on your file system. This will make things reproducible.

Comment: I have 6 files in the second `select`. Logging `vdump` actually prints out some files but incorrect (or exceeding) ones.

Comment: I would recommend looking at why it would be exceeding

Comment: @Jacob your fiddle works perfectly. So with my solution, I have to check my `for` for any error of some kind.

Comment: If you open your browser console in the JSFiddle you should see the `Uncaught TypeError` error message. However, I have moved the demo to the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Edit. Apologies to @David. I miss-read the name. Thank you for your help.

Thank you @CBCrusher for breaking down the steps to debug the issue.

As OP has narrowed the issue down to the for loop I will help out with a working example.

You are currently loop through the array from 0 -> length. However, you are removing elements inside the loop, this will change the length of the array, (giving you out of bounds errors). The trick to this is looping through the array backwards.

```js
function visible_selection() {
  var ext = document.getElementById("ext");
  var slen = document.getElementById("files").length;
  var selected = ext.options[ext.selectedIndex].text;
  var filez = document.getElementById("files");

  for (var i = slen - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var vdump = filez.options[i].text;
    var xcase = vdump.split(".");
    if (!vdump.includes(selected) && xcase[1] != selected) {
      filez.remove(i);
    }
  }
  filez.style.display = "inline";
}

document.getElementById("ext").onchange = () => {
  visible_selection()
}
```

```html
<label for="ext">Extentions:</label>

<select id="ext">
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an extention -- </option>
  <option value=".jpeg">.jpeg</option>
  <option value=".png">.png</option>
  <option value=".pdf">.pdf</option>
</select>


<label for="files">Files:</label>

<select id="files">
  <option disabled selected value> -- all files -- </option>
  <option value="File1.jpeg">File1.jpeg</option>
  <option value="Fiel2.jpeg">Fiel2.jpeg</option>
  <option value="Fiel3.png">Fiel3.png</option>
  <option value="Fiel4.pdf">Fiel4.pdf</option>
  <option value="Fiel5.pdf">Fiel5.pdf</option>
</select>
```